# Return Error Number 120022 on 'pj_thread_register ' in Linux

Tags: c, linux, pjsip

Operating system   : `Ubuntu 11.04 \n \l`
In Below Program `pthread` is creating new thread , but it fails when registering .

```
#include<pthread.h>
#include <pjlib.h>
#include <pjlib-util.h>

void serila_port_handler(void);

int main()
{
pthread_t trd_hndler;
    if(pthread_create(&trd_hndler,NULL,serila_port_handler,NULL))
    {
        printf("ERROR while initializing serial port_thread \n");
    }
    pthread_join(trd_hndler,NULL);
}
void serila_port_handler(void)
{
    int ret,rc;
        pj_thread_desc ptd;
        pj_thread_t *thread =0;
        bzero(&ptd, sizeof(pj_thread_desc));
        if ( (rc = pj_thread_register("serialportthread",ptd, &thread)) != PJ_SUCCESS) {
                printf("Error in pj_thread_register Return Val.: %d\n",rc);
                exit(1);
        }
        printf("pj_thread_register Success!");
        sleep(10);

}
```

Output:

```
Error in pj_thread_register Return Val.: 120022
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You [must](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest/pjlib/docs/html/index.htm#configure_app_sec) call [pj_init](http://www.pjsip.org/docs/latest/pjlib/docs/html/group__PJ__BASIC.htm#ga069615152140fa2df009cebc8a36b769)() before using anyting in pj-lib.

If this still causes problems, you need to debug pj-lib, which includes figuring out what error code 120022 means, and read the source code for pj_thread_register to figure out what is happening.

Comment: Hi @nos , Your suggestion Worked. Thank You very much , I was trying for last 2 days., Thanks Once again!